# Looking for EVT_DIRCTRL_FILEACTIVATED in the latest wxPython. It is missing

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to handle the event EVT_DIRCTRL_FILEACTIVATED emitted by a GenericDirCtrl (as specified in the docs), but it doesn't seem to exist. It mentions something about wxWidgets - is that different to wx? How does it work with wxPython?

Comment: Which version of wxPython are you referring to? 3.0 or Phoenix?

Comment: This is 3.0 - but evidently I'm reading the documentation for Phoenix. I thought Phoenix was just what the documentation server was called. Heh.

Comment: Actually, it says the same thing in both. I'm still confused. Grepping for the string even turns up nothing.

Comment: I asked on the wxPython IRC group, bu haven't heard anything yet. You should try posting on the wxPython Google group. They might know what's going on.